# restore sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, restore

I want to restore a database using asp.net web application in C#..
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

simple example

```
public bool RestoreDB(string dbName, string backupPath, string newLocation,string userName,sring Password)
        {            
            ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(serverName);
            if(userName=="")
                con.LoginSecure = true;
            else{
                con.LoginSecure = false;
                con.Login = userName;
                con.Password = Password;         
            }
            Restore restoreObj = new Restore();         
            var srv = new Server(con);
            if (srv != null)
            {
                restoreObj.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
                restoreObj.Database = dbName;
                BackupDeviceItem resDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(backupPath, DeviceType.File);
                restoreObj.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
                restoreObj.ReplaceDatabase = false;                
                restoreObj.Devices.Add(resDevice);                 

                restoreObj.PercentComplete += (sender, evtargs) =>
                {
                   //on progress callback
                };

                restoreObj.Complete += (sender, evtargs) =>
                {
                   //on competion callback
                };

                restoreObj.SqlRestoreAsync(srv);

            }
            return true;
        }
```